# Why am I getting this error Route doesnt exist both on browser and postman why i have done eveerthing correct

Tags: node.js, testing, postman, backend

**Routes**here this is my route where i defined the auth rouutes

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { register, login } = require('../controllers/auth')
router.post('/register', register)
router.post('/login', login)

module.exports = router
```

**app.js ** and i have ran the server is on

```
 require('dotenv').config();
 require('express-async-errors');
 const express = require('express');

const app = express();

//connect to the db
// const connectDB = require('./db/connect');


//routers
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth')
const jobsRouter = require ('./routes/jobs')



// error handler
const notFoundMiddleware = require('./middleware/not-found');
const errorHandlerMiddleware = require('./middleware/error-handler');

app.use(express.json());
// extra packages

// routes


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('jobs api');
});

app.get('/auth/register', (req,res)=>{
  res.send('This is the bullshit')
});


app.use(notFoundMiddleware);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);

app.use('/api/v1/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/jobs', jobsRouter)

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    // await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

**controller **  here is the controller for testing logic for my routes

```
const User = require('../models/User');

 const register = async (req,res) =>{
    res.send('register user');
};

const login = async (req,res) =>{

    res.send('login user');
};

module.exports = {
    register,
    login,
}
```

what is the matter why don't i get thee response from
localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/register and
localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/login

here is the image for my postman i am not getting the response and i have used post request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kGhs.png)

Comment: I don't see a /register anywhere. From your code, you should have /auth and /jobs. I think you might have to include the code for your auth controller

Answer (score 0):

You've imported the routes but haven't added them to your `app`

```
//routers
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth')
const jobsRouter = require ('./routes/jobs')

app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRouter ); // <<<<< use authRouter for path /api/v1/auth
app.use("/api/v1/jobs", jobsRouter );
```

By the way, when you've already defined `/register` path in your `authRouter` , the code below is not required:

```
// This is redundant and should be deleted
app.get('/auth/register', (req,res)=>{
  res.send('This is the bullshit')
});
```